# Real time ffmpeg / x264 encoder behavior when input resolution suddenly changes

Tags: ffmpeg, libx264

I want to take a live HD-SDI signal being captured by a capture card and encode it in real time to X.264.

What happens when the input resolution suddenly changes? eg, from HD SDI 1080/50i to HD SDI 720/59p, etc.

Does the encoder handle that gracefully? Or would there be some artifacts/disturbance in the output? (or worse?)

Comment: Haven't come across that scenario but you could apply a scale, deinterlace and fps filter so that libx264 is processing frames with the same properties.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I don't think that will work well. The encoded content written to disk must later be played back out an HD-SDI card at the original resolution and frame rate (of course at a lower quality). Modifying the frame rate on encode will introduce some unacceptable artifacts.

Answer (score 1):

FFmpeg will automatically insert scale filter to rescale to first resolution when it encounters input resolution changes. Obviously this only applies when encoding.